# Can I serve a react app (with react router) from a specific endpoint?

Tags: reactjs, django, react-router

I have a Django app. Most of the endpoints for this app will serve up a template. However, I would like one endpoint, lets say example.com/xyz, to serve a React app. This react app uses routes, so it would manipulate the url path.

My question comes in two parts:

1. If it is possible to do this, how can I ensure React router keeps the original /xyz endpoint in the path before adding whatever else to it?
2. How can I configure Django to return the react app for ANY endpoint that begins with /xyz?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes; set a [`basename` for your router](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) to `/xyz`.
2. With a [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/#re-path) á la `re_path(r'^xyz/.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="template_rendering_react_app.html")),`